# Mysterious piece of metal shipped with a soldering iron

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

This piece of metal was packaged with my new soldering iron.

[image: Mysterious piece of metal]

Does anybody know what is it ? Is it a stand ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is a stand, if you push out the center piece so that it is about 45 degrees or more from the rest of the metal then you have a stand which will hold the iron off the surface.
This tends to come with the Maplin irons in the UK.

Comment: Thanks ! I was not sure it was a stand: I fear that it will become too hot for my table when holding the iron. As for the iron itself, it is branded "Antex", but it seems that Maplin/Antex sells the same products anyway.

Comment: If you prop the plastic part on the soldering iron handle on the stand then it will not get hot.

Comment: As the iron will be resting on the edge of the metal stand, there will not be enough surface area to conduct the heat from the iron to cause a scorch mark on the table top. Personally, I found that the sand to be too light but it's a freebie really.

Comment: @JonathanD - Also, if it is steel, the thermal conductivity is quite low. It will not get significantly hot anywhere but the small area near where the iron touches.

Comment: Bin it and get a proper one, like this: http://uk.farnell.com/antex/st-4/stand-for-antex-soldering-iron/dp/155214 - you'll appreciate it later!

Answer (score 5):

Yup, [it's a stand](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Soldering-Iron-Accessories-Kit-Set-Tools-Solder-Stand-Desolder-Braid-Wire-/141027512470) - here's a photo of it assembled:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The holes are for securing it to the bench with a couple of screws.

Comment: I think the holes are just strain relief but as you say they can be used to fasten the stand to a bench.